# Matrices with components defined by polynomial equations are open

Tags: general-topology, matrices

Let $F$ be a field, with a topology such that the field operations are continuous. Let $U$ be an open subset of $F$, and consider the collection of matrices
\begin{equation}
A=\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} | \begin{cases} a= y\\ b =x+ yu\\ c= v\\d=vu \end{cases},x,y,u,v  \in U\}.
\end{equation}
Can one conclude $A$ is open because the components come from adding and multiplying elements of an open subset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that you did not define a topology on $\mathcal{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F})$. But since this is a vector space of finite dimension, all norms being equivalent, I will guess that you impose on this space the topology induced by $\mathbb{F}^4$.

Now, lets work out the equations. $a=y,y\in U$ simply implies that $a\in U$. Similarly we have $c\in U$. Now we have $d=uc$ for some $u\in U$, which means that $dc^{-1}\in U$ and finally $b=x+adc^{-1}$ implies that $b-adc^{-1}\in U$.

Consider the map $\varphi:A\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^4$ defined by
$$\varphi(\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}) = (a,b-adc^{-1},c,dc^{-1})$$

Since these operations are continuous, $\varphi$ is continuous. Moreover, $A=\varphi^{-1}(U\times U\times U\times U)$ is the pre-image of an open subset under a continuous map. Therefore $A$ is open.